# How to logout user from the Facebook when he does not authorize the application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have ASP.NET web application that

1. Runs on public computers
2. Allows users to register by using their Facebook accounts.
3. Must always logout a user from the Facebook after registration has been completed.

Registration process contains the following steps:

1. Registration page is shown with the Facebook icon.
2. When user clicks on the Facebook icon, he is redirected to the Facebook web site.
3. On the Facebook site user enters his email and password and clicks login.
4. On the Facebook site user clicks Allow to authorize my application.
5. User is redirected to my application.
6. The application registers used in the database.
7. The application calls FB.logout in order to logout from the Facebook. So when new user starts registration he cannot use account of previous user.

The application works perfect until user clicks Cancel at step 4.
When this happens, the browser is redirected to my application, the user remains signed into the Facebook but the application is not authorized by this user. This means that the application cannot logout this user from the Facebook by using the FB.logout method because the application does not have access token.

How to logout from the Facebook in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How to logout from the Facebook in this case?

Not possible at all.

*If* logging a user out *without* a valid access token was possible, then *every* website I’m visiting could do that if they liked – I’m sure you can see how annoying that’d be to users, and that it’s therefor not possible.

Comment: It makes sense but it is not consistent because API allows to logout from the Facebook when the application has only basic access to user information.

Comment: It only allows log out if you have a user access token.

Comment: I already said why this _should_ not be possible any other way, and Facebook has made sure it isn’t.

Comment: This does not make sense because it still allows ANY site that you authorized to log you off.

Comment: Yes – and if a site was to exploit that and log users out of Facebook without them actually wanting this to happen, after a few complaints it’ll be easy for Facebook to shut that specific application id that site was using down. And _that’s why_, again: It’s just _common sense_ on Facebook’s part resp. of the OAuth specification, to allow an app to log a user out of the FB web platform _only with a valid access token_ for that particular user.

Comment: Again, this is not consistent. A common sense would be to DO NOT allow ANY application log users out of the Facebook or DO allow ANY application to log users out. Look at the scenario that I described. This is a security issue. How do you suggest to handle it with this common sense?